# OPC UA .NET Client - Can't Create Transport with UaTcpBinding

Tags: opc, opc-ua

Anyone know why the UaTcpBinding binding class is missing in the latest OPC.UA.Core.dll?

When creating the ApplicationConfiguration.TransportConfiguration, I thought you had to add a TransportConfiguration to the collection, like:

```
Instance_of_ApplicationConfiguration.TransportConfiguration.Add(
    new TransportConfiguration
    (Utils.UriSchemeOpcTcp,typeof(Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaTcpBinding)));
```

Is there a trick to creating an ApplicationConfiguration with the default 'opc.tcp' transport?

UaTcpBinding appears in OPC.UA.Core.dll v1.0.238.1

UaTcpBinding is not in OPC.UA.Core.dll v1.2.336.0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're familiar with the original WCF-style bindings. Some are still there in the latest release:

```
// Opc.Ua.BindingFactory
private static void AddDefaultBindings(Dictionary<string, Type> table)
{
    table.Add("http", typeof(UaSoapXmlBinding));
    table.Add("net.tcp", typeof(UaSoapXmlOverTcpBinding));
    table.Add("net.pipe", typeof(UaSoapXmlOverPipeBinding));
}
```

But the new release prefers you to use Session.Create() which is hardcoded to look for endpoints starting with "opc.tcp" (or "https") and will create an TcpTransportChannel (or HttpsTransportChannel).

No need to set a TransportConfiguration any more.

Comment: A-ha!  That makes sense.  I was reading the logs and config XML of the OPC Foundation's latest Sample OPC Client and noticed it made mention of TcpChannel, so I suspected it used a different approach to the transport.Hyla-soft's code on GitHub (https://github.com/hylasoft-usa/h-opc) uses the method you mention, so I'll give that a shot and report back for all to see.  Thanks!